# Create two lists of object attributes in Python

Tags: python, list, object, attributes

I have a list of objects in python

```
objects = [Obj1, Obj2, Obj3]
```

These objects have attributes

```
Obj1.value
Obj1.datatype
Obj2.value
Obj2.datatype
```

I am trying to create two lists, each containing a particular attribute of my list of objects

```
values = [Obj1.value, Obj2.value, Obj3.value]
datatypes = [Obj1.datatype, Obj2.datatype, Obj3.datatype]
```

I know I can make one list using

```
values = [o.value for o in objects]
```

Is there a pythonic way to make both lists? 
I could definitely do it using a for loop,

```
values = []
datatypes = []
for o in objects:
    values.append(o.value)
    datatypes.append(o.datatype)
```

I was just wondering if there was a more elegant way. I'm pretty new to Python.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why would you want separate lists of the attributes? Just access the ones you need when you need them.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is probably the most Pythonic and the most efficient already.

You *could* do this:

```
data = [(o.value, o.datatype) for o in objects]
values, datatypes = zip(*data)
```

but while that saves lines, it is less efficient as it involves two iterations of the list rather than one.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to avoid two iterations. Thank you for your input, and I'll stick with the for loop.